# String operation on env variables on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a question regarding Kubernetes YAML string operations.

I need to set an env variable based on the hostname of the container that is deployed and append a port number to this variable.

```
 env:
    - name: MY_POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.name
```

> How do I create another env variable that uses MY_POD_NAME and makes
>   it look like this uri://$MY_POD_NAME:9099/

This has to be defined as an env variable.  Are there string operations allowed in Kubernetes YAML files?

Answer (score 72):

You can do something like

```
- name: MY_POD_NAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.name
- name: MY_POD_URI
  value: "uri://$(MY_POD_NAME):9099/"
```

We are using that since K8s 1.4

`$()` is processed by k8s itself, does not work everywhere, but works for env variables.

If your container contains bash, you can also leverage bash variable expansion

```
"command": ["/bin/bash"],
"args": [ "-c",
         "MY_POD_URI_BASH=uri://${MY_POD_NAME}:9099/ originalEntryPoint.sh
       ],
```

`${}` is not touched by k8s, but evaluated later in container by bash. If you have a chance, prefer the first option with `$()`

**note**: order matters in declaration. In example above, if `MY_POD_NAME` is defined later in env array, the expansion will not work.

Comment: Thanks! Just a note: order matters in declaration. In example above, if `MY_POD_NAME` is defined later in env array, the expansion will not work.

Comment: Great answer, a pointer to the right place in the K8s docs would be helpful.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/

Comment: What if this is a secret from a Secret object? Will this be evaluated and exposed?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly.

You should run a startup script using the Pod ENV variables you have accessible to set any additional variable that you need, and launch your service after that in the startup script.

Comment: back in 2016 it was not possible.
now you can use env variables in pod definitions.